# Как транслитеровать латинские символы в кириллицу на Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, c, кириллица

Задача: приложение для Linux, которое будет подобием CrazyKeys (https://www.soft-4u.net/homepage/soft-windows/sistema/893----crazykeys-174) - подменяет вводимые символы на кириллицу. Причем не побуквенно, а, например, "sh" на "ш", "ya" на "я" и т.д.

В какую сторону стоит копать и возможен ли такой перехват на Linux: получать вводимые символы с клавиатуры, не позволять им появиться в активном окне и явно передать для вставки нужные кириллические символы?

Утилита планируется на C++.

Comment: читайте символы из стандартного ввода, обрабатывайте и пишите в стандартный вывод, который подключен как стандартный ввод целевого приложения.

Comment: @user7860670, скажите пожалуйста, применима ли эта концепция для глобальной работы в ОС, т.е. для перехвата всех приложений, а не только в окне моего условного процесса?

Comment: Конечно, все это возможно (но вандализма я не люблю (да и время для таких экзерциссов не подходящее))

Comment: Гуглить в сторону "IME" ("Input MEthod").